# Printed wpf visual is clipped in landscape mode under Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, bitmap, landscape

I have a simple wpf desktop application which prints a bitmap in landscape mode.
Under Windows 8/8.1 the printout is clipped on the bottom of the page while under Windows 7 it is printed correctly.
The code is really simple: load a bitmap, put it into an Image object, measure the printable area, arrange the image and print.

```
 void printButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var pd = new PrintDialog();

        if (!pd.ShowDialog().Value)
        {
            return;
        }

        pd.PrintTicket.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
        pd.PrintTicket.PageBorderless = PageBorderless.None;

        var printingCapabilities = pd.PrintQueue.GetPrintCapabilities(pd.PrintTicket);

        var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        bitmapImage.BeginInit();
        bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri("D:\\printTest.bmp");
        bitmapImage.EndInit();

        var imageuiElement = new Image { Source = bitmapImage };

        var desiredSize = new Size(printingCapabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth, printingCapabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight);
        imageuiElement.Measure(desiredSize);
        imageuiElement.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(printingCapabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginWidth, printingCapabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginHeight), imageuiElement.DesiredSize));

        pd.PrintVisual(imageuiElement, "MyImage");
    }
```

The bitmap size is 1518 x 1092 pixels, 96 DPI, which is 40.2 x 28.9 cm.

I have found the question [Cannot print a document with landscape orientation under Windows 8 (WPF, .NET 4.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27999769/cannot-print-a-document-with-landscape-orientation-under-windows-8-wpf-net-4)
but there is no good response for my issue (additionally I have no problem with printing as landscape itself).
I have tested it with different printers of different vendors, the printouts are clipped in all of them. A software CutePDF writer prints it to PDF correctly.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Windows 8 does not draw ui elements outside of their container bounds. This is why the printout was clipped at the bottom. 
Anyway, I ended up with a code like this, which is able to print a centered bitmap on a landscape page:

```
printDialog.PrintTicket.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
            printDialog.PrintTicket.PageBorderless = PageBorderless.None;

            var printingCapabilities = printDialog.PrintQueue.GetPrintCapabilities(printDialog.PrintTicket);
            if (printingCapabilities.PageImageableArea == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var document = new FixedDocument();
            document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize = new Size(printingCapabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth, printingCapabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight);

            foreach (var imageStream in imageStreams)
            {
                document.Pages.Add(GeneratePageContent(imageStream, printingCapabilities, printDialog.PrintableAreaWidth, printDialog.PrintableAreaHeight));
            }

            try
            {
                printDialog.PrintDocument(document.DocumentPaginator, GlobalConstants.SoftwareName);
            }

private PageContent GeneratePageContent(Stream imageStream, PrintCapabilities printingCapabilities, double paperWidth, double paperHeight)
    {
        imageStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        var bmp = new BitmapImage();
        bmp.BeginInit();
        bmp.StreamSource = imageStream;
        bmp.EndInit();

        var margin = new Thickness();
        var pageSize = new Size();

        if (printingCapabilities.PageImageableArea != null)
        {
            margin = new Thickness(
                printingCapabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginWidth,
                printingCapabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginHeight,
                printingCapabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginWidth,
                printingCapabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginHeight);

            pageSize = new Size(printingCapabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth, printingCapabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight);
        }

        var imageUiElement = new Image
        {
            Source = bmp,
            Margin = margin
        };

        var canvas = new Grid { Width = paperWidth, Height = paperHeight };
        canvas.Children.Add(imageUiElement);

        var fixedPage = new FixedPage
        {
            Width = paperWidth,
            Height = paperHeight
        };

        fixedPage.Children.Add(canvas);

        var pageContent = new PageContent();
        ((IAddChild)pageContent).AddChild(fixedPage);

        pageContent.Measure(pageSize);
        pageContent.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(), pageSize));
        pageContent.UpdateLayout();

        return pageContent;
    }
```